# What keys should I keep for later?

Tags: dead-cells

In some maps, you will find yourself with multiple keys and the doors where to use it, just to discover later on a door locked with a key from a previous map.

What are the keys it makes sense to keep and for which map, at least once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game has 11 different keys:

- **Gardener's Key (3)**
- **Moonflower Key (3)**
- **Cavern Key**
- *Village Key (2)*
- Old Service Key (3)
- Clockmaker's Key
- Bell Tower Key
- Graveyard Key
- Architect's Key
- Castle Key (3)
- Crypt Key (4)

You can use one **gardener's key** each in the ramparts, the graveyard, and the forgotten sepulcher to collect the moonflower keys. To take a route through all three of those places you need to have 3 active boss cells.

You need all 3 **moonflower keys** in high peek castle to unlock the blueprint "Acceptance".

You need the **cavern key** in the graveyard to open the path to the cavern. You only need to do this once.

The **village keys** are noteworthy, though not required in a different stage. There are 2 keys and 3 doors in the stilt village. 2 locked doors will block your way towards the end of the stage, where you will find a third door that you need to open to get the blueprint for the counter shield.

> You can skip the first door by taking a secret path above it. Doing this allows you to take one of the keys to the third door

Read [here](https://deadcells.gamepedia.com/Pickups#Keys) for more information on keys.